# How do I pass arguments to Web UI's dwc compiler from build.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I want to turn off URL rewriting by dwc (the Web UI compiler). I run dwc via build.dart. How do I pass an argument from build.dart down to dwc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any arguments after `--` will be passed to dwc.

```dart
void main() {
  var args = new List.from(new Options().arguments);
  args.addAll(['--', '--no-rewrite-urls']);

  build(args, ['web/clock_page.html']);
}
```

Read more about [dwc](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/tools.html).

Comment: Perhaps mention that the arguments are passed as an ordered list.